# pine script error - end of line without line continuation

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I try to write code on tradingview for making a determinate signal. But inside of my code, when i try to save the indicator, i receive the indentation error on the portion of the code that i have post here. The line of the error are the firsr (if).
Error: end of line without line continuation

I have try to change in version4 but the result not change, i see always the same error

Some one can help me to solve?

```
if (ta.candleColor(0) == 1 and 
    high[1] > prevClose and 
    low[0] < prevClose and 
    currentOpen > prevClose) 
    sellSignal := true
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is no such ta function in pine script as ta.candleColor(0), but for the solution let's assume you've written a custom one.

```
if candleColor(0) == 1 and 
     high[1] > prevClose and // indent +1 to continue conditional
     low[0] < prevClose and // indent +1 to continue conditional
     currentOpen > prevClose // indent +1 to continue conditional
    sellSignal := true
```

You only have to increment your indentation by 1 if you want to use line breaks within conditionals or function calls.